# How to Fix PHP Deprecated : Factory::getDocument() is deprecated

Tags: php, javascript, joomla-4.x

How can I fix the following deprecation error generated by my php code?

> Factory::getDocument() is deprecated

```
$app = Factory::getApplication();
$wa = $app->getDocument()->getWebAssetManager();

if (!$wa->assetExists('script', 'keyselectmodal'))
{
    $document = Factory::getDocument();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Joomla\CMS\Application\WebApplication::getDocument()`. In your code you're already doing this with `$app->getDocument()`.

Comment: unexpected :: error.

Comment: In your code you only need to replace `Factory::getDocument()` with `$app->getDocument()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
$app = Factory::getApplication();
$document = $app->getDocument();
```

Or this:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Document\FactoryInterface;
$container = Factory::getApplication()->getContainer();
$documentFactory = $container->get(FactoryInterface::class);
$document = $documentFactory->getDocument();
```

You may notice there's an "Undefined method" error in Intelephense despite it being defined and valid.